# Does there exist a cryptographic associative hash function?

Tags: hash-function, one-way-function

Does there exist a function $f(x,y)$ with these properties:

1. Computing $f(x,y)$ is in P.
2. $f$ is associative:  $f(x, f(y, z)) = f(f(x, y), z)$.
3. $f$ is one-way (assuming P $\neq$ NP):  Given the value $v$ of some $f(x, y)$, zero or one of the values $x$ and $y$, and given that there exists a solution, it is difficult to compute a $z$ and $w$ for which $f(z,w) = v$.

Comment: I find it hard to call $f$ a cryptographic hash function, because while I don't have an example that violates your one-way property, collision resistance is trivially broken: $$f(f(v, x), y) = f(x, f(y, v)).$$

Comment: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/17935/351